# How can I test new aggregating framework of Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am waiting new aggregating framework of Mongodb. New aggregation framework query style documented in this [address](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) and it is written at top

> The Aggregation Framework was first available in MongoDB 2.1.0.

So where I can download it for try that version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right there: http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

In the "Development (unstable)" section.

Answer (score 1):

The "Development Release" nightly builds available at http://www.mongodb.org/downloads include the aggregation framework.