# How to group more than 20000 uniq key?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have 2 examples:

```
results = coll.group( key={"ip": 1, "id" : 1 }, condition= {}, initial={},
reduce="function(obj,prev) {}" )
print len(results)
```

and:

```
map = Code(
"function () {"
"emit({ id: this.id, ip: this.ip}, {count: 1});"
"}"
)

reduce = Code("function (key, values) {""}")
result = coll.map_reduce(map, reduce, "map_reduce_example")
print result.count()
```

Why second example more slowly than first ? I want to use 2 example instead of 1 example because 1 example not work for more than 20000 uniq key.

Comment: There is a third option (coming soon): MongoDB's new aggregation framework (http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/mongodbs-new-aggregation-framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're running map/reduce, your `map` and `reduce` functions are executed in javascript runtime (which is slower than native C++ code). This also involves some locking (JS locks, read locks, write locks).

`group`, on the other hand, might be executed more efficiently (more native code, less locks, etc).

Note that in a sharded enviroment, map/reduce is your only option for now (in future versions you'll be able to use Aggregation Framework).

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB's [new aggregation framework](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/mongodbs-new-aggregation-framework) will probably solve your problems, but until then **I suggest running map/reduce as a regularly scheduled background job and querying the collection resulting from map/reduce in real-time**. This will get the grouped count results much faster, but the counts may be slightly stale (depending on the last time the background map reduce was done.)

---

***Explanation:***

*MongoDB's map/reduce is much slower than group() for several reasons:*

- Intermediate conversions: BSON -> JSON -> BSON -> JSON -> BSON (MongoDB stores data in binary BSON, but JavaScript map() and reduce() need to be fed textual JSON)
- Javascript functions map() and reduce() must be interpreted by the single-threaded JavaScript engine

*MongoDB's native C aggregation functions are much faster, but one of their limitations is that all output must fit within a single BSON document (currently 16MB).* That is why there is a limit on the number of unique keys.

*MongoDB's aggregation framework will combine the best of both methods:*

- Native execution for speed
- No BSON conversions to/from JSON
- Results can be sent to a collection, bypassing the limitations set by a single document.

The framework is already [documented](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) and [available in development versions of MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650023/how-can-i-test-new-aggregating-framework-of-mongodb). The framework is scheduled for production release in Feb. 2012.